# React matchRoutes - server side rendering matching more than one route

Tags: react-router, react-redux

When I browse www.localhost.com:8080/abc - Main component fetchMethod is being called - and also the next component 'One' with the path path: '/abc/:param', is being loaded - when I console out the server code - below is my route set-up in server.js and routes.js - and this is a server side rendering app - with fetchData on every component.. what could be my issue for calling 2 components for one route?

Comment: Does `Main.fetchData` request a `/abc/:param` route?

Comment: No it does not,

Comment: Can you look at the node logs to see if a request is being made to `/abc/:param`?

Answer (score 2):

I've attempted to emulate the code as best as possible here in the snippet. For each request the function returns the expected route and the expected component.

In order to make this demo work I commented out `component.fetchData` and it works, so `component.fetchData` could be causing the issue. Perhaps `Main.fetchData` is making a request to a `/abc/:param` route?

If `component.fetchData` isn't the culprit, I would look into the `node` console to see if `/abc/:param` is actually being requested.

If a `/abc/:param` route isn't being requested it might have something to do with the Express setup. And if that's the case we'll need to see more of the code.

```js
const handleRoute = function(req, res, next) {
  let {
    path,
    component
  } = routes.find(
    ({
      path,
      exact
    }) => {
      foundPath = ReactRouter.matchPath(req.url, {
        path,
        exact,
        strict: false
      });
      return foundPath;
    }) || {};
  component.fetchData()
  return {path, component} 
  //component.fetchData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
  
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  static fetchData({ store }) {
    console.log('fetching data');
    return store.dispatch(actions.getMainData());
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getMainData();
  }
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/abc',
    component: Main,
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/abc/:param',
    component: 'One',
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/abc/def/:param',
    component: 'Two',
    exact: true,
  }
];

handleRoute({url: "/abc"});
handleRoute({url: "/abc/123"});
handleRoute({url: "/abc/def/123"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.2.0/react-router.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/438581/brett-dewoody - Hi thank you so much for your help - I have commented out that line and the component 'Two' route is not going in to 'One' action creators - but the Main component route is going to its action first and then going to the 'One' action creators...i am seeing this is in console. Not sure why

Comment: Ok my Main component is expecting params I guess - I am seeing TypeError: component.fetchData is not a function error - if I change the path of my 'One' component to path: '/abc/somethinghere:param', - then I see it is not going to One's action creator but throwing fetchData error?

Comment: Having a hard time following. Sounds like `fetchData` isn't a function. Is `fetchData` a method in the `Main` component? Do you have a public repo so we can see the code?

Comment: component.fetchData({ store, params: (foundPath ? foundPath.params : {}) }).then(() => {
        const state = store.getState();
        const preloadedState = JSON.stringify(state).replace(/</g, '\\u003c');

Comment: this is my fetchData call inside server.js - this common method call works well with other component that has params - but the Main route does not have any param..? not sure thats the reason? Sorry I do not have a public repo

Comment: fetchData is a method I have in all the 3 components - a static method - which I call from server.js

Comment: Can you update the question with the code of `Main` or one of the other components?

Comment: I have updated question with 2 components - Main which is having problems as it does not have any Params - One which is working fine - I am guessing the way I call fetchdata from server shud change? but how to make params optional?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/438581/brett-dewoody - WOW removing exact from routes - i am not seeing that error any more?/?? - I think thats the whole problem?

Comment: Could be that, or maybe the `static fetchData({ store })` part - you said `fetchData` for the `Main` component doesn't have any params. So the destructuring of `store` would cause an error. If there are no params change it to `static fetchData()`